# Why does Notepad++ disable the HexEditor plugin?

Tags: notepad++, plugins, hex-editor

[Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) is a great editor... The regular expression facility is stunted, but I can live with that. It is OK for most find/replace situations, and for the occasional others I'll just hop across to [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) (Unicode) or [TextPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextPad) (ASCII only).

However, I can't live without a hex editor on tap!

The Notepad++ *HexEditor* plugin seems to work fine... I use it frequently.

For some reason unknown to me, this plugin is forcibly disabled by Notepad++ whenever I upgrade to the latest version (of Notepad++), with a message something like ".. due to instability issues".
`HexEditor.dll` gets moved into a "quarantine" subfolder: `.\disabled`.

This sounds a bit ominous. I have searched high and low, and I have found nothing which makes any reference to this mysterious "instability".
The plugin is available on the Notepad++ plugins page (which lists third-party plugins, and is not, strictly speaking, a Notepad++ page), and there is no mention of instability.

What's going on? Does it randomly get it wrong and corrupt data? Does it crash Notepad++?

**Can I trust this plugin?**

Comment: Interesting question? Could it be that the problem was fixed on plug-in side and the Notepad++ side wasn't notified of it? In the end, you could always ask developers why is the plug-in tagged incompatible.

Comment: A Google search for *Notepad++ HexEditor instability* finds [a thread](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331753/topic/3530603) (number 2 only to this Super User question) which suggests HexEditor "can crash Notepad++ in some rare cases".

Comment: ...And here's a relevant-looking bug tracker search for open HexEditor bugs: [Notepad++ Plugins - Tracker: Bugs - Open - HexEditor](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?limit=25&func=&group_id=189927&atid=931289&assignee=&status=&category=&artgroup=&keyword=HexEditor&submitter=&artifact_id=&assignee=&status=1&category=&artgroup=&submitter=&keyword=HexEditor&artifact_id=&submit=Filter)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've been to Notepad++'s Sourceforge forum, and found some entries.

2009-12-09 [HexEditor v0.9.5 vs N++ v5.6.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/482781/topic/3483807)
2009-09-25 [Hex editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/482781/topic/3410441)
2009-09-11 [Hex-Editor v0.9.5 available](https://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/482781/topic/3396218)

It seems safe data-wise, with some display bugs which they're working out.. Good enough for me, as my main concern was the question of data corruption.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Hex Editor plugin was disabled for being unstable. This means that the plugin crashed Notepad++ in some situations. I encountered this problem myself when trying to save an edited file.

Earlier versions of Notepad++ don't have those problems with the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... Perhaps I was using it in a way which didn't trigger the bug.... In the 10 months since I asked the question, I've worked around the issue by using Emacs as my "serious" editor... (actually I've shifted camps entirely to Ubuntu, where I can still use Notepad++; running in `wine`..  :)

Comment: Plugin is enabled and working again

Comment: Kind of mysterious, since I've been using Notepad++ with the Hex Editor plugin for 6 years and never seen any crashes related to the Hex Editor. I have worked on very large files also (up to 2 GB).

Comment: @JuhaUntinen I never figured out what actually causes the crashes, I can only confirm that they can happen.

Comment: LOL why would one shift to an inferior OS while still have a working Windows license?

Answer (score 6):

Just put it back in the plugins folder and it works fine.

Comment: Bit of a pain every time Notepad++ upgrades.

Answer (score 3):

I too like the HexEditor plugin. I rolled back Notepad++ to an older version to be able to work with this plugin.
Now I checked the latest version on Notepad++ (v5.9.2 Unicode) with the latest HexEditor plugin (v.0.9.5 Unicode), and it works! The plugin is no longer disabled.

Comment: It's available but the Stability still says there are reported problems.

Answer (score 2):

Simply copying HexEditor.dll back from disabled to pluggins folder solves the problem. I haven't come across any crash.

Answer (score 1):

Some plugins are disabled by Notepad++ when you upgrade it :/. One of my favorite diff plugins got disabled a while back, and I have had to get a earlier version of Notepad++ to cope.

Answer (score 1):

Why? I have discovered the reason why only recently, so I might as well share it here. Well, it's one of the reasons or one of the possible scenarios.

First of all, I only started using the Hex Editor plugin for Notepad++ only recently. So I was not aware that Notepad++ had stability issues with this plugin. But it figures! The plugin has not been updated for a very long time (try six years), while Notepad++ has been updated regularly (a dozen in a year). At some point, Notepad++ became incompatible with this plugin.

It's not a major issue the way I see it. But I can understand why the author of Notepad++ wants to move past this plugin and disable it each time Notepad++ is updated to a new version. The installer script moves the plugin to a subfolder named "disabled".

I had some NFO files on my computer recently, and when I right clicked on one of the files and chose to edit it in Notepad++ from the context menu, Notepad++ crashed. I thought that was weird. So I started Notepad++ and then dragged and dropped the file onto it and it worked. So it crashed each time I used the context menu to open the file, and it worked each time I dragged and dropped the file or used the open file dialog.

A few weeks later I got the prompt telling me that a new version of Notepad++ is available. So I downloaded and installed it. This is the first time I got the message telling me that the Hex Editor plugin was unstable and had to be moved to the "disabled" folder.

[image: Dialog message]

I had a thought that this might be what had been causing the crashes. As it turned out, it was! Right now I am using version 6.9.2 of Notepad++ and 0.9.5 of Hex Editor plugin on Windows 10 version 1511 (10586.494). As soon as I move the DLL file for the Hex Editor to the plugins folder to enable it, and then use the context menu to open a file, it crashes the program. If I shut it down, move the DLL file back to the disabled folder, then it does not crash when using the context menu.

[image: Crash error]

*Note! This only happens if the file name extension is NFO! So for a file with the name extension of TXT is not affected. I have not tested a lot of the other file name extensions I have on my computer, but I did test a few of them (e.g. JPG) and it appears as if only files with NFO extensions are affected.*

In case someone finds this interesting, here is what to do to replicate it.

1. Install Notepad++ version 6.9.2.
2. Install Hex Editor plugin version 0.9.5.
3. Create a new dummy file on the Desktop named dummy.nfo.
4. Right click on the file and choose Edit with Notepad++.

*Note that some older versions of Notepad++ will trigger the bug as well. I don't know what version introduced this issue. But if you use a too old version then the error will not appear.*

Answer (score 0):

There is only a problem the first time you launch the Hexeditor plugin.

The settings of Notepad++ and plugins are stored in your userprofile (%USERPROFILE%\Appdata\Roaming\Notepad++).

I found that when the files are created correctly then Notepad++ starts perfectly, but think it's a combination of files as I tried deleting one by one, but no result.

I removed all plugins and added one. I then started Notepad++, closed Notepad++, and added the next plugin until all your plugins were added.

Answer (score 0):

The Hex Editor plugin works for me without any hassles.
I'm using Notepad++ 6.8.8 with Hex Editor 0.9.5.

I only found one issue, which is solvable, where Notepad++ fails to start correctly.
Notepad++ can be seen in Task Manager and that it is consuming more and more memory.
The reason for this behaviour is that the directory `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\config` is missing (e.g. for a newly created user).

To solve this:

- End all the user's Notepad++ processes via Task Manager
- Create the missing directory either via Windows Explorer or via the following command line
  `mkdir "%APPDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\config"`
- After this Notepad++ will start normally again

Still it is [a bug in Hex Editor](https://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/bugs/215/) with recent Notepad++ releases.
But in my point of view nothing to call the Hex Editor plugin unstable.