# Show hexadecimal/ASCII codes on Notepad++ 6.3

Tags: notepad++, ascii, hexadecimal

Is there a way to show the hexadecimal/ASCII for all text showing in the editor?

I use Windows XP and Notepad++ 6.3

Comment: Related: *[Why does Notepad++ disable the HexEditor plugin?](https://superuser.com/questions/163006)*

Comment: Cross-site duplicate (or the other way around): *[A hex viewer / editor plugin for Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617888)*

Answer (score 19):

If you're just looking for non-standard character values, you can select View > Show Symbols > Show all characters.

Classical ASCII values below 32 will be shown with the names in the top right picture [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). "HT" is the Tab character with ASCII value 09, "LF" is linefeed (newline character), and so on. But most of the rest will show a hex code for the value if it's not an actual visual symbol in the current encoding.

Comment: Notepad++ guys need to review their menus as I just spent 10 mins looking for it in preferences.

Answer (score 11):

Here you can find a lot of plugins for Notepad++: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/

An hex-editor-plugin is along too: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the plugins mentioned above, there's the TextFX plugin 
(explained here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699833/textfx-menu-is-missing-in-notepad )

With it, you can select TextFX Convert > Convert text to hex-16

Answer (score 5):

I've found the HEX_Editor for Notepad++ x64.

https://github.com/chcg/NPP_HexEdit/releases

Answer (score 3):

In fact there is a plugin that comes as an "HexEditor.dll" with 270336 byte in size. Copy it to "plugin" folder.

It works with 32-bit version of Notepad++ only. Looks like there is no 64-bit Version. Unfortunately NPP disables the plugin (moves to disabled folder) when upgrading NPP. It says there are known issues. I've never ran into those. it works fine for me.
Sourcecode is available and one really should forge the code and redo some stuff.
I recommend the use of free hex-editor "hxd" anyway for more than a quick view into the binary.

Comment: I found a sequence of chars that did not show up in Notepad++ show all symbols.  They did show up in HxD.  They are there shown as E2 80 8B.

Comment: [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) <-- I second that. See both hex and ASCII. Edit, insert, delete, save. It's dreamy.

Answer (score 3):

Doug LN's answer is the correct one and it has made my life so much easier.  It is the 64 bit compliant plugin.  To get it to work on actual versions e.g Notepad++ Version 7.8.5 64bit on Windows 10 (as far off from the time of OP's question):

1. From https://github.com/chcg/NPP_HexEdit/releases download the x64 version: HexEditor_0.9.8_x64.zip (or whatever the latest version is)
2. Extract HexEditor DLL to the notepad++ plugin directory (typically C:\Program Files\Notepad++\Plugins)
3. Launch Notepad++, click PLUGINS| PLUGINS ADMIN...
4. Find "HexEditor" in the list, select it, and click INSTALL
5. Notepad++ should restart, if not, do so.
6. Open binary file, then select PLUGINS | HEX-Editor and presto.

Comment: on notepad 7.9.3 i can install this from plugins|plugins admin without first downloading.