# how to type indian and greek numerals

Tags: ime

i'm getting quite used to typing in different scripts using the microsoft ime
recently though i'm getting more and more interested in numerals other than the usual 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

i would like type indian numerals and greek numeral and maybe other i don't know yet

is there a way to type these numerals overal not just in word or excel?

p.s. i do know that most greek numerals are just their letters but i can't find koppa and sampi at all :/

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/576431/notepad-inserting-special-unicode-characters-in-utf-8

Comment: um that's notepad i said overal ασδφ<like how i can type this but for numerals

Comment: @Fuseteam if you can type it in notepad you can type it in pretty much anything, though I guess your point is perhaps that you are talking about IME, so e.g. perhaps you want typing  'a' to produce alpha.  You can do that with or without google input tools download  It is something you can try here https://www.google.com/inputtools/try/   You can change language in the language bar, and then choose google input tools.

Comment: @Fuseteam Greeks today would use the regular "english/hindi/arabic" numerals.  but it looks like you may be able to type it with greek letters https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/8189f8581e0141d20a11c0d1d4290e7af256c7ea  e.g. googling ancient greek numerals, the greek letter pi was one of the symbols used by ancient greeks to type numbers.

Comment: i can use a ime to type all letters yes but i can find the letter and remain after the transistion to arab-indian numbers namely the one for the "letters" called koppa and sampi used for 90 and 900(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/280165103398289419/280178407566999552/unknown.png) they used to be letters but are now still used similar to how we use roman mumerals

Comment: two years late but i meant i "can't" find the letters called koppa and sampi on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to use the [compose key](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose)
you should be able to assign a dead key sequence to the desired character(s) or request it from the maintainers.

The compose key is standard on linux btw :p