# How to read/open a midi file?

Tags: notepad++, midi

I need to read inside the midi file to find the data about the notes for a school project.

I tried to open random midi files on notepad++, but it does not open up in hexadecimal format as this website suggests:
[Website here](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html)

It just gives me a bunch of scrambled text

The purpose of findind the notes from the midi file is to play these notes on a DIY build player piano.

Comment: How would you play the notes? If it is with a program, you should look on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add a hex editor. Here is a link to hex editor plugin for notepad++:https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fnpp-plugins%2Ffiles%2FHex%2520Editor%2F&ei=Bu1eVIPaGcipyATumYH4Bg&usg=AFQjCNHGKXw258k2FZKunhVizc_tIGMfOw&sig2=m3xOSSMmUC7FOXJvv1tBew&bvm=bv.79189006,d.aWw

Comment: This plugin [crashes Notepad++](http://superuser.com/questions/163006/why-does-notepad-disable-the-hexeditor-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I use [FL studio](http://www.image-line.com/flstudio/) to read and create midi files. If you just need to read it. "Go to File > Import Midi File" then you can read it from there. The only problem for me that the program itself can take time to download and install.

Although you use synthesia which only plays midi. It doesn't have the flexibility like FL studio has.